# Get matching linear-gradient lines to stay still during responsiveness

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I've been trying to figure this out for a week. So I have the following code...

https://codesandbox.io/s/linear-gradient-lines-dbbjb

The top and mid lines stay connected as you move the window responsiveness, but the bottom line disconnects and moves left and right side of the mid/bot line connection. Is there a way to make it stay connected and still the whole time during the responsiveness?

I'm also open to other solutions (not using linear gradient), if I get the same styling. below is the full source code from the codesandbox:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

const DivWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
`;

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  html,
  body,
  #root {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
      'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
      sans-serif, cursive;
    background-color: #10101f;
    height: 100%;
  }
  *, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }

  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

const DivContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
`;

const DivTop = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  background-color: #013a6b;
  background: linear-gradient(
    95deg,
    #004e95 49.75%,
    #7fff00 50%,
    #7fff00 calc(50% + 3px),
    #013a6b calc(50% + 4px)
  );

  @media (max-width: 900px) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
`;
const DivMid = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #004e95;
  background: linear-gradient(
    85deg,
    #013a6b 49.75%,
    #7fff00 50%,
    #7fff00 calc(50% + 3px),
    #004e95 calc(50% + 4px)
  );
`;

const DivBot = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  background-color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    transparent 52.75%,
    #7fff00 53%,
    #7fff00 calc(53% + 3px),
    transparent calc(50% + 4px)
  );

  @media (max-width: 900px) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <DivWrapper>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <DivContainer>
        <DivTop />
        <DivMid />
        <DivBot />
      </DivContainer>
    </DivWrapper>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I have made a solution for you please check
https://codesandbox.io/s/linear-gradient-lines-shkos

Comment: hmmm it's a decent attempt, but I want the line to connect to the line above. So the 50% for right/left holds it in place, but if I change it to `left: 52.8%;` and `right: 47.2%;`... the line connects... but moves/disconnects upon responsiveness.

Comment: So... keeping it at 50% and adding padding-left seems to do the trick. Thanks ^^

Comment: there also seems to be another issue, resizing the window height-wise, makes the middle and top lines move...

Comment: It's in react. So why you dont go for js solution. like onResize event. I think that will give you 100% solution. If so dont forget to unsubscribe the resize event upon unmount the component.

Comment: I'm not sure what code to put in on the `onResize` event though. Unless you mean adding a media query where I would have the adjust the linear-gradient percentage every 10 pixels or so... but being there monitors bigger than mine that I cannot test with, I'm not sure this would be the proper solution.

Comment: major props to one of my coding bootcamp cohort students to figuring this out. just have this line of code `left: calc(50% + (((100vh - 60px) / 2) * 0.0875) - 30px);`, she used trigonometry to deal with the changing of the dimensions.